# Would this work to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

Is the code below better at preventing a SQL injection on a MySQL database than `mysqli_real_escape_string` would be?

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '; DELETE FROM customers WHERE 1 or username = '";
$str2 = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
{
    if (strpos ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,.?!0123456789", $str[$i], 0) !== FALSE)
    {
        $str2 = $str2 . $str[$i];
    }
}

echo "$str2";
```

Comment: Why would you try to create your own escaping code when code has been made that does the same and has been made by a lot of people that know way more about the subject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is **absolutely no reason** to use a whitelist/blacklist when trying to avoid SQL injection. All you need to do when using the `mysqli_` functions without prepared statements is to process data with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

However, you'd be better off learning about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead. They are cleaner and safer than escaping.

The code to execute your example query with prepared statements would look like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Since you don't understand the example, here's a detailed explanation:

- Line 1 prepares the statement. You use `?` whenever you want to use external data.
- Line 2 binds a string (`s`) parameter for the first placeholder. So `$username` should contain the (untrusted) value
- Line 3 executes the statement with the previously bound parameter. SQL and data is transferred separately so there is no SQL injection risk.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use mysqli_real_escape_string() then. I'm not yet advanced enough to understand your code example.

Comment: Please try to understand it. Anyone who'll have to work with your code later will love you for it. And you *will* forget to escape some argument and thus open a security hole. Feel free to join the [PHP chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) if you need some help understanding how to use prepared statements.

Comment: I really would love to, but there's only so much time in a weekend and I just need to see some things work instead of opening a can of worms that I can not see or test (!!!) because I have no knowledge about it. I realize that it's important and my question got triggered by not at first understanding the difference between i and no i. Again, I'm trying to build a simple comment system for my website and there's a lot of things that keep falling apart and that I have to put together again. The mysqli_real_escape_string and a google reCAPTCHA must do the trick for the moment.

Comment: A captcha does not help AT ALL against SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the code below better at preventing a mysql injection than mysqli_real_escape_string or does it not matter?

Neither. It is worse and you should not do it! Instead of escaping(!) data(!!) you are breaking your whole query.

In short, it will

1. make valid queries not work
2. not prevent malicious queries

Even if you apply your method just on the data, not on the whole query, it will

1. mess with your data
2. not prevent all kinds of SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Read [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). On the bottom, where users comments are, you will find a lot of useful SQL injection prevention tricks and hints.
The first step, however, is to validate and sanitize yout GET/POST data before inserting it into a query.